# Добавить в span <i class></i>

Tags: jquery

Впервые столкнулся с тем, что нужно добавить в span еще и `<i class></i>`, как в этом примере: `<span id="Department"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large btn-default"></i></span>` но что-то не выходит:

```
$("#Department").append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large btn-default">'+ 'Hello world' + '</i>');
```

Значение появляется, но класс пропадает.

Comment: вместо `+ '</span>'` надо `+ '</i>'` ?

Comment: Хотя браузер итак должен правильно всё подставить. Возможно это не полный код. Либо стоит пояснить что значит "но класс пропадает"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Department"></div>

        <script>
            $(function() { // код ниже исполняется когда все DOM элементы документа будут построены на странице и доступны
                $("#Department").append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large btn-default">'+ 'Hello world' + '</i>');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Использовал jQuery версии 3.4.1

Вариант 2:

```
var i = $('<i></i>');
$(i).addClass('glyphicon');
$(i).addClass('glyphicon-th-large');
$(i).addClass('btn-default');
$(i).text('Hello world');
$("#Department2").append(i);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если в цикле? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015845/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-class-%d0%b2-bootstrap-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-append-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: Страница не найдена(

Comment: Извиняюсь, уже разобрался, мой косяк ))

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, вполне работает.

```
document.getElementById("Department").innerHTML += ('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large btn-default">Hello world</i>');
```